# Kotlin Firebase: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.Model.perizinan

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load data from Firebase to RecyclerView, I need to get data from Firebase to ArrayList but I get the below **error**:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.Model.perizinan
```

this is my **class**:

```
class perizinan(val imageUrl:String, val namakegiatan:String, val keterangan:String, val waktuKegiatan:String, val presensiIzin:String, val tanggalkegiatan:String)
class izin(val perizinan:List<perizinan>)
```

this is my **code**:

```
fun readFirebaseDatabase(){

    val ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Admin")
    ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("AdminActivity","cancelled")
        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid

            p0.child(uid!!).children.forEach{

                it.children.forEach{

                val posts = ArrayList<perizinan>()

                for (snapshot in it.children) {
                    val post = snapshot.getValue(perizinan::class.java)
                    posts.add(post!!)
                }

                    RecyclerViewAdmin.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@AdminActivity)
                    RecyclerViewAdmin.adapter = adminAdapter(izin(posts), this@AdminActivity)

                }
            }


        }
    })

}
```

below is **my database structure**:

[image]

Comment: The first uid under `Admin` node is the `uid` of the logged in user and the second and third one are the ids of what?

Comment: the second uid is from the sender of the message and the third is the message uid, this is like chat app

Comment: So you want to get all post under the logged in user id or under the message uid? Which in first case is just one.

Comment: under message uid please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are using a wrong reference when trying to get a `perizinan` object from the database. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
val ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Admin")
```

to

```
val ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Admin")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)
    .child(senderId)
```

and

```
p0.child(uid!!).children.forEach{ /* ... */ }
```

to

```
p0.children.forEach{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: but i can't show to recyclerview, hahaha fix this problem come other problem :v

Comment: Ya, this is happening all the time. This sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question, so please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.